# Pass Generic Delegate Argument To UnityEvent

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine, delegates

I am setting up a registry for callbacks (my own event handler system).

Client code is supposed to call `Register` and they can add a function to handle an event when its fired. So for example say FunctionA and FunctionB are both subscribed to "GOT_HIT" event, both functions will be invoked.

I know UnityEvents are the way to go but I can't seem to actually add methods to them. I cannot get the syntax right if I am using an argument. Here is my code which is erroring out on `_battleEvents.AddListener(handler);` because:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ActionHandler' to 'UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction>'

Here is my best attempt at the code specifying a delegate type:

```
public class ActionEvent:UnityEvent<Dictionary<string, Object>>
{

}

public delegate void ActionHandler(Dictionary<string, Object> props);

public class Dispatcher
{
  static Dispatcher _singleton = new Dispatcher();
  static Dictionary<string, Object> _subscriptions = new Dictionary<string, Object>();

  static ActionEvent _battleEvents = new ActionEvent();


  public static void Register(string actionName, ActionHandler handler)
  {
    switch(actionName)
    {
      case "battle":
        _battleEvents.AddListener(handler);
        break;
      default:
        Debug.Log("Error");
        break;
    }
  }
```

If you can tell me how I can make my `handler` parameter correctly such that I can add any function I want to pass that would be ideal.

I am able to get it to work when I pass in an anonymous function like so:

```
_battleEvents.AddListener((Dictionary<string, Object> props) => { });
```

But I want to be able to set it from the argument.

I *could* just invoke my actual handler in there as such:

```
_battleEvents.AddListener((Dictionary<string, Object> props) => {handler(props); });
```

But I'm trying to skip that.

I.E. I'd like to do this:

```
  public static void Register(GenericDelegate handler)
  {
      // _battleEvents is UnityEvents object
      _battleEvents.AddListener(handler);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

The key was to use the `UnityAction` class:

```
  public static void Register(string actionName, UnityAction<Dictionary<string, Object>> handler)
  {
    switch(actionName)
    {
      case "battle":
        _battleEvents.AddListener(handler);
        break;
      default:
        Debug.Log("Error");
        break;
    }
  }
```